# SQL Update first instance of record - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have an import process that needs to  update the "End Date" of the older record in a table. The import comes from someone else and some of the details I need to match specific user info are missing. What I need to do is update the older record, which, in the example below, would be the `UserID = 1`, and not update `UserID = 4`.

I have the following sql to update, but as you can tell, it updates both records:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.[EndDate] = t2.[EndDate]
FROM ExistingUser AS t1, ImportUser AS t2
WHERE (t2.[uName] = t1.[uName]) AND (t1.[EndDate] IS NULL);
```

Disclaimer: I did not create the database and cannot redesign the tables, so please take pity on me. Thanks!!!

ExistingUser - Table

```
UserID    uName   BeginDate    EndDate
  1       John   01/01/2013
  2       Mary   05/01/2014   04/30/2015
  3       Bob    12/01/2014
  4       John   06/01/2015
```

ImportUser - Table

```
uName    EndDate
John    05/31/2015
```

Comment: what about if you first UPDATE the rows in the ExistingUser-Table and then INSERT the new ones in one transaktion? because it seem so, that there is no unique constraint on the ExistingUser-Table which allows only unique values vor uName and Enddate.

Comment: If you don't mind an answer from Microsoft, you could use [TOP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/ms180971%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) as shown in the second example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by building a subquery that numbers the entries by username that do not have the `EndDate` populated.  This subquery would look like this:

```
SELECT [UserID], [uName],
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [uName] ORDER BY [BeginDate]) AS IX
FROM ExistingUser
WHERE [EndDate] IS NULL
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/72c49/2

```
| UserID | uName | IX |
|--------|-------|----|
|      3 |   Bob |  1 |
|      1 |  John |  1 |
|      4 |  John |  2 |
```

In this subquery, the two records with the same `uName` of `John` are numbered in order by `BeginDate`.  Now if we join the original `UPDATE` query to this subquery searching for records with `IX=1`, we will only update the earliest rows.

```
WITH EarliestExistingUser AS (
  SELECT [UserID], [uName],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [uName] ORDER BY [BeginDate]) AS IX
  FROM ExistingUser
  WHERE [EndDate] IS NULL
)
UPDATE t1
SET t1.[EndDate] = t2.[EndDate]
FROM ExistingUser AS t1
  JOIN EarliestExistingUser AS t1f ON t1.UserID = t1f.UserID
,ImportUser AS t2
WHERE (t2.[uName] = t1.[uName]) AND (t1.[EndDate] IS NULL)
AND (t1f.IX = 1)
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/72c49/3